# List object is not callable IN PYTHON

Tags: python, list, function, object, filter

```
def new(l):
    return l%2==0

list(filter(new,range(4,31)))
```

please someone resolve this. I am getting a error that list object is not callable

Comment: You must have used `list` as a variable name at some point, e.g., `list = [1,2,3]`. Now `list` doesn't refer to the type itself, but to an *instance* of the type.

Comment: If this is a script, just change the variable name. If this is an interactive session, you can either restart the interpreter, or you can use `del list` to clear the variable and let the name resolve against the built-in definition again.

Comment: and that is the reason we ask for a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @chepner Not necessarily. Could also be `filter` or `range`.

Comment: @superbrain True, but `list` is more likely.

Comment: @chepner Yes, with "likely" instead of "must have" I'd agree.

Answer (score 1):

This one will work. Only reason it will fail because you have declared `list` as a variable somewhere in your code like `list = ....`, so the builtin type gets overwritten. If you are doing from script change the variable name using Find and Replace in Text editor, or if you are in python shell then use `del list`, or restart the shell but you have to re-do things (but python history file will help you to restore)

Comment: Yeah I tried the same code in other file and it worked .                                                                       Thanks a lot